# Using databases in a distributed WSO2 API Manager setup

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, api-manager

it's known that when we uses a distributed WSO2 API Manager setup it is necessary uses 3 databases like:

[image: DataBases at APIManager]

When we use a standalone setup we have 2 datasources:

- WSO2_CARBON_DB (The datasource used for registry and user manager)
- WSO2AM_DB (The datasource used for API Manager database)

1 Question: If WSO2_CARBON_DB is substuited by REGDB and USERDB, can I remove the  datasource WSO2_CARBON_DB from master-datasources.xml?

2 Question: If I use LDAP , is it necessary create the USERDB?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Question: If WSO2_CARBON_DB is substuited by REGDB and USERDB, can I
>   remove the datasource WSO2_CARBON_DB from master-datasources.xml?

Yes, you can remove WSO2_CARBON_DB, if you have seperate databases for users and registry.

> Question: If I use LDAP , is it necessary create the USERDB?

Yes, we need that database. API Manager keeps LDAP user group and API Manager permission mappings in that database. LDAP group will function as roles in API Manager, and you can assign permissions to those roles.

Comment: Saying "you can remove WSO2_CARBON_DB", you are saying the contrary of Bhathiya here : "in a production environment, it is recommended to separate them as WSO2_CARBON_DB, WSO2UM_DB and WSO2REG_DB (Please note you need WSO2_CARBON_DB too, to store local data.)" source : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38734196/about-wso2-api-manager-data-sources?rq=1 Who is right please ?