# About WSO2 API Manager data sources

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm performing WSO2 API manager + Analytics 2.0 POC now. When i change datasource from H2 to Oracle, in wso2am-2.0.1-SNAPSHOT, there are 2 data source config files:
master-datasources.xml & metrics-datasources.xml, according [Installing and configuring the databases](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Clustering+API+Manager+2.0.0#ClusteringAPIManager2.0.0-ConfiguringtheTrafficManager), there should be WSO2AM_DB, WSO2UM_DB and the WSO2REG_DB datasource configurations, but i just find WSO2_CARBON_DB & WSO2AM_DB, so my questions are

1. Is **WSO2_CARBON_DB = WSO2UM_DB + WSO2REG_DB**?
2. for **WSO2_METRICS_DB**, according [Enabling Metrics and Storage Types](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Enabling+Metrics+and+Storage+Types), if we enable JDBC storage, can we store all components metrics information in one shared db or it needs one db per component(local)?
3. What's **WSO2_MB_STORE_DB** used for? from the scripts, it's for Message Store and Andes Context Store. Can we keep to use H2 in prod. cluster env.?

When i config wso2am-analytics-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT, i have below questions:

1. Can we share **WSO2_CARBON_DB** setting for both APIMGRT related components and analytics? or it's better to not share?
2. For **WSO2AM_STATS_DB**, is analytics resposible to aggregate and write to it, APIMGRT responsible to read? Which APIMGRT components need to read it?
3. For analytics related store, it supports RDBMS, Cassandra, HBase, but it does not support mongodb, right?
4. for **GEO_LOCATION_DATA**, What's this used for? Can we just use H2 in prod. env.?

Comment: For one question you asked, it is not recommended to use H2 in prod environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

APIM:

1) In default pack, yes. But in a production environment, it is recommended to separate them as WSO2_CARBON_DB, WSO2UM_DB and WSO2REG_DB (Please note you need WSO2_CARBON_DB too, to store local data. And this can be an h2 database)

2) You can have a shared DB

3) WSO2_MB_STORE_DB is required only if you use [Advanced Throttling](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/blob/v6.0.4/features/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.core.feature/src/main/resources/config/api-manager.xml#L463). Tables for this are created by APIM itself. So you don't need to run any scripts on it.

APIM Analytics:

1) You can share WSO2UM_DB and WSO2REG_DB. But don't share (local) WSO2_CARBON_DB.

2) Store and Publisher

3) See [WSO2 DAS with MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35865501/wso2-das-with-mongodb)

4) GEO_LOCATION_DATA is used for [Geolocation Based Statistics](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Configuring+Geolocation+Based+Statistics). H2 is not recommended.

Comment: In 2.0 , Does it just support REST client, but not external RDBMS? [Analytics](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Introducing+the+WSO2+API+Manager+Statistics+Model). It seems there are no stats db scripts in {APIM_HOME}/dbscripts like 1.10 and there are build-in C-App in wso2am-analytics-2.0.0. right?

Comment: Both c-app and stat db scripts are packed to wso2am-analytics-2.0.0 from 2.0.0 onwards. And you don't need to run those scripts manually in 2.0.0. They will be automatically run and tables are created when the C-App is installed.

Comment: Yes, i had tried it. So my concern is that when wso2am 2.0.0 integrated with wso2am-analytics-2.0.0, the default method is REST client, and we do not need to config WSO2AM_STATS_DB at API Manager side(used as external RDBMS client?)， right?

Comment: Actually it's the opposite. We have removed REST client due to performance issues. So the default is `<StatsProviderImpl>org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.client.impl.APIUsageStatisticsRdbmsClientImpl\</StatsProviderImpl>` in api-manager.xml.
So you have to configure STATS_DB.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification, got it, they shared the stat db via `jdbc:h2:../tmpStatDB/WSO2AM_STATS_DB;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=60000;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE`.

Comment: Correct. That's the default configuration.